# Sum of Column value

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to sum up all the column value from particular table and get the total as a double. This is my current function to do it

```
  public String sumAll() {
  float columntotal = 0;
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_RPI,
            KEY_RLP, KEY_RSK, "sum("+ KEY_RNP +")", KEY_RTP};
    Cursor c = mDb.query(PENGELUARAN_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    if (c != null) {
       c.moveToFirst();
      columntotal = c.getFloat(0);
      }
    String  sumtotal = Float.toString((float)columntotal);  
    return sumtotal;
}
```

But the function above just give me the total number of the column in the table instead. How could I modify those function so it returns the total value of the column?

Comment: you missed  columntotal += c.getFloat(0);

Comment: My bad, The answer is because the columnindex I selected for `c.getFloat(0);` is the 0th index which is the `KEY_RPI` not the column I wanted to sum up from. It should be `c.getFloat(3)` whic is the `"sum("+ KEY_RNP +")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate functions cannot be used with simple columns unless simple columns are in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Either provide `groupBy` parameter or remove all columns from the query except `sum(KEY_RNP)`

EDIT:  [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) actually allows aggregate queries without `GROUP BY` clause but the results for non-aggregate columns are selected randomly and are not particularly useful.

> If the SELECT statement is an aggregate query without a GROUP BY clause, then each aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once across the entire dataset. Each non-aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once for an arbitrarily selected row of the dataset. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each non-aggregate expression. Or, if the dataset contains zero rows, then each non-aggregate expression is evaluated against a row consisting entirely of NULL values.